# How to use AND in IF Statement

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check:

**IF** cells (i,"A") contains the text 'Miami' **AND** (i,"D") contains the text 'Florida' **THEN** change value of cell (i,"C") to BA.

```
Sub ABC()
Dim wsh As Worksheet, i As Long, lngEndRowInv As Long
Set wsh = ActiveSheet

i = 2
lngEndRowInv = wsh.Range("A" & wsh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
While i <= lngEndRowInv
    If Cells(i, "A") like "*Miami*" And Cells(i, "D") like "*Florida*" Then
        Cells(i, "C").Value = "BA"
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you value exact matches on a case sensitive basis? ie how is `If LCase$(Cells(i, "A")) Like "miami*" And LCase$(Cells(i, "D")) Like "*florida*" Then`

Comment: @brettdj No, they are not case sensitive.

Comment: I think we will need to see your file. Christian Specht has answered this is as best as it can without seeing your data

Comment: @brettdj Thanks for all your help. I was able to find the solution. `Sub ABC()
Dim wsh As Worksheet, i As Long, lngEndRowInv As Long
Set wsh = ActiveSheet

i = 2
lngEndRowInv = wsh.Range("C" & wsh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
While i <= lngEndRowInv
If Cells(i, "A") Like "*Miami*" And (Cells(i, "D") Like "*Florida*" Then
Cells(i, "C").Value = "BA"
End If
i = i + 1
Wend
End Sub`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Brief syntax lesson**

`Cells(Row, Column)` identifies a cell.  Row must be an integer between 1 and the maximum for version of Excel you are using.  Column must be a identifier (for example: "A", "IV", "XFD") or a number (for example: 1, 256, 16384)

`.Cells(Row, Column)` identifies a cell within a sheet identified in a earlier With statement:

```
With ActiveSheet
  :
  .Cells(Row,Column)
  :
End With
```

If you omit the dot, `Cells(Row,Column)` is within the active worksheet.  So `wsh = ActiveWorkbook` `wsh.Range` is not strictly necessary.  However, I always use a With statement so I do not wonder which sheet I meant when I return to my code in six months time.  So, I would write:

```
With ActiveSheet
  :
  .Range.  
  :
End With
```

Actually, I would not write the above unless I really did want the code to work on the active sheet.  What if the user has the wrong sheet active when they started the macro.  I would write:

```
With Sheets("xxxx")
  :
  .Range.  
  :
End With
```

because my code only works on sheet xxxx.

`Cells(Row,Column)` identifies a cell.  Cells(Row,Column).xxxx identifies a property of the cell.  `Value` is a property.  Value is the default property so you can usually omit it and the compiler will know what you mean.  But in certain situations the compiler can be confused so the advice to include the `.Value` is good.

`Cells(Row,Column) like "*Miami*"` will give True if the cell is "Miami", "South Miami", "Miami, North" or anything similar.

`Cells(Row,Column).Value = "Miami"` will give True if the cell is exactly equal to "Miami".  "MIAMI" for example will give False.  If you want to accept MIAMI, use the lower case function:

```
Lcase(Cells(Row,Column).Value) = "miami"
```

**My suggestions**

Your sample code keeps changing as you try different suggestions which I find confusing.  You were using `Cells(Row,Column) <> "Miami"` when I started typing this.

Use

```
If Cells(i, "A").Value like "*Miami*" And Cells(i, "D").Value like "*Florida*" Then
  Cells(i, "C").Value = "BA"
```

if you want to accept, for example, "South Miami" and "Miami, North".

Use

```
If Cells(i, "A").Value = "Miami" And Cells(i, "D").Value like "Florida" Then
  Cells(i, "C").Value = "BA"
```

if you want to accept, exactly, "Miami" and "Florida".

Use

```
If Lcase(Cells(i, "A").Value) = "miami" And _
   Lcase(Cells(i, "D").Value) = "florida" Then
  Cells(i, "C").Value = "BA"
```

if you don't care about case.

Comment: @user823911.  Just noticed that I had my Lcases in the wrong place.  If the code worked you must have noticed my mistake and corrected it but sorry for any confusion.  I have corrected my code for the benefit of any future visitor.

Comment: @user823911 While Tony has provided useful background here it isn't clear to me "what worked" as I don't think there is additional material beyond what had been provided by Christian with `If Cells(i, "A") like "*Miami*"` or my comment on `LCase$`. So for anyone else looking at this what was your issue?

Comment: I understand brettdj's question.  At the time my answer was accepted, I had Cells(i, "A").Value = Lcase("miami").  I cannot believe I made that mistake.  The only explanation I can offer on user823911's behalf is that the background information was the true answer.

Answer (score 4):

If there are no typos in the question, you got the conditions wrong:

You said this:

> IF cells (i,"A") contains the text 'Miami'

...but your code says:

```
If Cells(i, "A") <> "Miami"
```

--> `<>` means that the value of the cell is **not equal to** "Miami", so you're not checking what you think you are checking.

I guess you want this instead:

```
If Cells(i, "A") like "*Miami*"
```

---

**EDIT:**

Sorry, but I can't really help you more. As I already said in a comment, I'm no Excel VBA expert.
Normally I would open Excel now and try your code myself, but I don't even *have* Excel on any of my machines at home (I use OpenOffice).

Just one general thing: can you identify the row that does not work?
Maybe this helps someone else to answer the question.

Does it ever execute (or at least try to execute) the `Cells(i, "C").Value = "BA"` line?
Or is the `If Cells(i, "A") like "*Miami*"` stuff already `False`?
If yes, try checking just one cell and see if that works.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, you are right. My bad. I wanted this If Cells(i, "A") like "*Miami*". However, when I use it with AND it doesn't work. Can you identify any other errors:                                          i = 2
lngEndRowInv = wsh.Range("A" & wsh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
While i <= lngEndRowInv
If Cells(i, "A") Like "*Miami*" And Cells(i, "D") Like "*Florida*" Then
Cells(i, "C").Value = "BA"
End If
i = i + 1
Wend

Comment: I'm not really an Excel VBA expert (I know VBA, but I only use it in Access, so I've never used Excel-specific stuff like `Cells`). But generally: how do you know that this code is not okay? Does it do something else than you expected? Does it do nothing at all? Do you get an error message? If yes, what is it?

Comment: I run it line by line and simultaneously see my Excel sheet; and the thing it's supposed to do it's not doing.

Comment: It works well until I include AND. Works perfectly well till -- If Cells(i, "A") like "*Miami*" then Cells(i, "C").Value = "BA".

Comment: And you are sure that you really have a row in your Excel sheet where Cell A contains "Miami" and Cell D contains "Florida"...?

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply looking for the occurrence of "Miami" or "Florida" inside a string (since you put * at both ends), it's probably better to use the InStr function instead of Like. Not only are the results more predictable, but I believe you'll get better performance.

Also, VBA is not short-circuited so when you use the AND keyword, it will test both sides of the AND, regardless if the first test failed or not. In VBA, it is more optimal to use 2 if-statements in these cases, that way you aren't checking for "Florida" if you don't find "Miami".

The other advice I have is that a for-each loop is faster than a for-loop. Using .offset, you can achieve the same thing, but with better effeciency. Of course there are even better ways (like variant arrays), but those will add a layer of complexity not needed in this example.

Here is some sample code:

```
Sub test()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cell As Range
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    If InStr(1, cell.Value, "Miami") <> 0 Then
        If InStr(1, cell.Offset(, 3).Value, "Florida") <> 0 Then
            cell.Offset(, 2).Value = "BA"
        End If
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I hope you find some of this helpful, and keep at it with VBA! ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think you should append .value in IF statement:

```
If Cells(i, "A").Value <> "Miami" And Cells(i, "D").Value <> "Florida" Then
    Cells(i, "C").Value = "BA"
End IF
```

Comment: @user823911 this is becaise it leaves out the `*` wildcards

Comment: @brettdj So how do I go about it?